How to preprocess/encode categorical data, to use in dimensionality reduction and clustering algorithms?
I am working on a project witht the goal of clustering participants of in a survey according to their answers. The dataset is a set of 63 questions, some nominal and some ordinal. How should I encode the data before using dimensionality reduction algorithms like tsne amd then clustering algorithms like kmeans and hierarchical clustering ?

Although you question is quite broad, I mean you can read a whole lot of chapters out there. Still I'd mention my approach.

I try to understand nature of Data i.e. look for categorical variables and
cardinality. High cardinality can pose challenges for some encoding techniques.
Next step is to encode. There are several encoding techniques
Label Encoding, One-Hot Encoding, Binary Encoding, Frequency Encoding,Target Encoding
Handle high cardinality as per your obervations.
Dimensionality Reduction Techniques: After encoding, techniques like PCA (Principal Component Analysis) or t-SNE (t-Distributed Stochastic Neighbor Embedding) to reduce dimensions.
Scaling and Normalization
Standardization: Adjust the encoded values to have a mean of 0 and a standard deviation of 1. This is particularly important for algorithms sensitive to scale, like PCA.
Normalization: Adjust the encoded values to fall within a specific range, typically [0, 1].
Feature Engineering
Combining Categories: For high-cardinality features, consider combining less frequent categories into an "Other" category to reduce dimensionality.
Creating Interaction Features: Sometimes interactions between categorical variables can be important. Creating new features based on these interactions can provide more information to the algorithms.
Algorithm-Specific Considerations
Clustering Algorithms: Algorithms like K-means and hierarchical clustering require numerical input and benefit from features being on a similar scale. Encodings should ensure that categorical data is represented in a way that preserves meaningful distances between points.
Dimensionality Reduction Algorithms: Algorithms like PCA, t-SNE, and UMAP (Uniform Manifold Approximation and Projection) work on numerical data and are sensitive to the scaling of input features.
Evaluation and Iteration
Visualization: Use visualization techniques like pair plots or heatmaps to understand the relationships and distributions of encoded features.
Model Performance: Evaluate the performance of clustering algorithms and dimensionality reduction techniques using metrics like silhouette score, Davies-Bouldin index, or explained variance ratio for PCA.

Iterate: Experiment with different encoding techniques and preprocessing steps to find the best combination for your specific dataset and task.
Example Workflow
Identify categorical variables: Country, Gender, Job Title.
Choose encoding techniques:
Country: One-hot encoding.
Gender: Label encoding.
Job Title: Frequency encoding.
Encode the data.
Scale the data: Apply standardization.
Apply dimensionality reduction: Use PCA to reduce dimensions.
Cluster the data: Use K-means clustering.
Evaluate results: Check cluster quality using silhouette score.
Dimensionality Reduction
Dimensionality Reduction important points
